# PyGame for Python 3.5

Tags: python, pygame

I am running Python 3.5 and I want to install PyGame, the website only supports up to version 3.2. I have tried a few forums on this and other websites but they are all for Python 3.4. Does anyone know were I can find the install file for Python 3.5 and how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which OS you are using, but I just successfully installed PyGame directly from Mercurial on OS X for Python 3.5.1 (via Homebrew, `brew install python3`) with the following command:

```
pip3 install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

This should work on Linux as well.

```
% python3.5
Python 3.5.1 (default, Feb 16 2016, 16:10:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame
<module 'pygame' from '/Users/thp/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py'>
```

I haven't tried on Windows, but [this blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/) has some suggestions on how to make compiling Python C extensions on Windows work, for different Python versions -- apparently you just need to install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: On Windows [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) is always a friend. He did it already.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows and you have installed Python via Anaconda (which I recommend) you can simply open Anaconda prompt and simply type `pip install pygame` and you 'll get the latest version.